# Call function from within dictionary

Tags: python, arrays, function, dictionary, call

I've been trying to wrap my head around this problem, I've found a few solutions but no joy.
Basically I have a dictionary with keys and a corresponding function. The purpose of the dictionary is to link to particular support guide. I take input from the user. Using this input i search the dictionary and if the keys the function is called.

```
Python3.6

class Help():
  def load_guide(self):
    while True:

        print("Which Guide would you like to view")

        for manual in Help.manuals:
            print (f"{manual}",end =', ')

        guide_input= input("\n> ")
        if guide_input in Help.manuals:

            Help.manuals.get(guide_input)
            return False 

        else:

            print("Guide not avalible")

  def manual():
      print("Build in progress")
  def introduction():
      print("Build in progress")


  manuals = {
  'Manual' : manual(),
  'Introduction' : introduction()
  }
```

I've tried a few variations but each presents a different problem.

```
Help.manuals[guide_input] | No action performed 
Help.manuals[str(guide_input)] | Error: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
Help.manuals[guide_input]() | Error: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
Help.manuals.get(guide_input) | No action performed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you initialise your dictionary like this:

```
def manual():
    print("Build in progress")

manuals = {'Manual' : manual()}`
```

the return value of the `manual` function will be stored in the dict because you call the function during the initialisation (`manuals()` is a function call). Because the function doesn't return anything, the value stored in the dictionary under the `'Manual'` key is `NoneType`:

```
>>> type(manuals['Manual'])
<class 'NoneType'>
```

So you have to change the way the dictionary is initialised in order to have a *reference to the function* stored in the dict. You can do this by not calling the function during the dictionary initialisation (note the missing `()`):

```
>>> manuals = {'Manual' : manual}
>>> type(manuals['Manual'])
<class 'function'>
```

Then all you need is get a reference to the function from the dictionary by using `manuals['Manual']`, and call that function `manuals['Manual']()`.

```
>>> manuals['Manual']
<function manual at 0x7fb9f2c25f28>
>>> manuals['Manual']()
Build in progress
```